# Test pointer events in ie with modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, modernizr

pointer-events:none isn't functioning in ie, yet

```
Modernizr.testAllProps('pointerEvents');
```

returns true in ie. Please help me make ie tell the truth, or if it is telling the truth why can't I implement it like I can in other browsers?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/80 where this is discussed along with the detect's testing and results: https://github.com/ausi/Feature-detection-technique-for-pointer-events/wiki

Are you using a recent build of Modernizr? If so, chime in with a reproducible case on the #80 thread.

Comment: Hi Paul, I didn't see the non-core detects section and hadn't checked the pointer-events checkbox. After re-generating the build it all worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will be a flag in [Modernizr 3+](http://v3.modernizr.com/download/) (v3 is currently in beta beta). The usage is very simple:

```
if ( Modernizr.csspointerevents ) {
    // use pointer events
} else {
    // do fallback magic
}
```